# I want to add, delete, update etc my database in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a class `MyDBHandler` extending `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

I want to perform add,subtract,update,delete etc on my database through an `asynctask` class as suggested by `developer.android.com`.
I don't understand what are the params i should pass to the async task class method `doInBackground` in my `(new DBTasksAsync.execute(?<--here))`
as i will further implement operations such as `getWritableDatabase()` and `getReadableDatabase()`  in my Asynctask

```
public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT";
    private static final String COMMA_SEP = ",";
    private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
        "CREATE TABLE " + MyDatabase.DatabaseEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                MyDatabase.DatabaseEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                MyDatabase.DatabaseEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                MyDatabase.DatabaseEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE + TEXT_TYPE + " )";

    private static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES =
        "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + MyDatabase.DatabaseEntry.TABLE_NAME;
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDBHandler.db";
    public MyDBHandler(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    public void doChanges(){
        DBTasksAsync dbTasksAsync=new DBTasksAsync();
        dbTasksAsync.execute();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onOpen(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)    {
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: well, maybe instead of `AsyncTask` you should use `AsyncQueryHandler`?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a common practice to add background operations in your SQLiteOpenHelper. You can keep it synchronous and components which are using it will be responsible for asynchronously. Or you can move the logic with concurrency to the separate [Repository](https://medium.com/@krzychukosobudzki/repository-design-pattern-bc490b256006#.mlbqdp1ro) class.

Overall performing database operations in the background doesn't differ a lot from performing any others short-term background operation. And you can find plenty of articles on this : 
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html,https://developer.android.com/training/best-background.html,
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html